# Is there an implicit presence validation in active record associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing

I am relatively new to TDD, and I was writing a unit test to ensure that a `wishlist` can't be saved without a corresponding `user`. Here is my giftlist model class:

```
class Giftlist < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Here is my user model class:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable

  has_many :giftlists
end
```

My test looks like this:

```
test 'wishlist must have an associated user' do
  @giftlist = Giftlist.new
  assert_not @giftlist.save, 'wishlist was saved without user'
end
```

I was expecting this test to fail since I haven't added `validates :user, presence: true` to my wishlist model. However, the test passed which led me to believe that rails does some implicit validations on foreign key associations.

Is this what is happening? Or is something else going on?

Answer (score 1):

I feel that this sort of behavior would be easier to express using [Shoulda Matchers](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda) instead.  With that, you can write your behavior and expectations tersely without having to do any boilerplate.

```
it { is_expected.to belong_to(:user) }
```

But, what your immediate problem seems to be is an improper use of [`assert_not`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Testing/Assertions/assert_not).  `assert_not`, from my reading of the documentation, *negates* the expression you're evaluating against (and turns `nil` to `true`).

In this scenario, you want to assert that the test object *does* save successfully, else print out the error message.

```
test 'wishlist must have an associated user' do
  @giftlist = Giftlist.new
  assert @giftlist.save, 'wishlist was saved without user'
end
```